# Messed up file permissions

Tags: permissions, files, chmod

Not being an expert in Linux/Ubuntu, I had to install from scratch today and messed up w/file permissions.

The thing is that, when backing everything up before reinstalling, a couple of important documents couldn't be copied to the external drive, so I used `gksudo nautilus` to be able to.

Now I've copied them back and I can't use them. They are locked, a lock icon appears on a corner and the original error message shows again.

Is there a graphical/easy way to set file permissions back to normal?

I've read about `chmod` `fchmod` and `chown` and I would like to avoid them if possible. If there's no choice, can any of you please give me a quick example on how to use it?

Thank you so much Ub. Community!

Comment: `chmod +rw file.txt` and `chown gcwilkins:gcwilkins file.txt`

Comment: @GCWilkins Welcome to AskUbuntu! If your question has been resolved, can you mark it as such by [accepting](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask) the answer below you found most helpful rather than by making an edit? You can do so by clicking the checkmark icon next to the desired answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'll have a look at the forum rules & procedures when I have a min!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To chmod on many files at a time just use the -R thingy to do it recursively(subfolders, files etc).

So if I am in folder `/myfolder` and I want to make all files/subfiles/folders/subfolders in there to belong to me and have all accesses I would do:

```
chmod -R 770 *
chown -R myname:myname *
```

So just replace `myname` with your name in Ubuntu. You don't need to change anything in the first one.

Comment: Thanks! I SOLVED it using your lines for the sake of terminal economy...!

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the file, select 'Properties' in the context menu, then chose the 'Permissions' tab. This allows you to set permissions within Nautilus.

If you run Nautilus as superuser (`sudo nautilus`) then you can also change owner of the file.

Comment: I already realized that on my own, but thank you very much! Now I wonder if there is a way of doing that or applying chmod to a bunch of files and directories at the same time.

Comment: Just select a bunch of files and right-click and select Properties and do the same. Or you right-click on a folder, and select Properties, then Permissions then press the "Apply Permissions to Enclosed Files" button.

Answer (score 0):

No click and point method springs to mind. Here's the command line method (type these in to a terminal):

```
# set up some variables: userid to hold the UID and group to hold the GID
userid=$(id -u)
group=$(id -g)
sudo chown ${userid}:${group} <file> ...
chmod 600 <file> ...
```

This code first grabs your userid and group (see `man id`), then changes the file(s) ownership(s) to you (see `man chown`). This has to be done as `root` (see `man sudo`) because we don't know the current ownership. Then, when the files(s) belong to you, we change the permissions to Owner:read/write,Group:,Other:. If the  is a directory (folder) change the last line to

```
chmod 700 <file> ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I now understand file permissions and chmod/chown better!